# reCaptcha TypeError on resubmit after timeout

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I set up a test page to work with the Google reCaptcha and am getting an error when the session times out and I try to resubmit. I have a demo showing what happens at http://kexp-web1.cac.washington.edu/GCap.html

Repro Steps

1. Page loads
2. Click "I'm not a robot" checkbox
3. Wait for session to time out
4. See warning "Verification expired.
5. Check the box again
6. Receive Javascript warning in console "Uncaught
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null"

   [image: Console Log]

It seems like this should be a pretty simple error, but I can't find what it might be. Anyone experience this before?

UPDATE (9/11/15)
I added the following in, not sure if this was the proper way to handle, but it seems to work.

[image]

Comment: 1) link is 404     2) how long is session time out?    3) post your javascript code (and HTML that is calling reCaptcha)   4)  does captcha work if you don't "wait for session to time out"?  5) what version of reCaptcha are you using? 6) most people would of downvoted you by now (i didn't) for not  being specific and clear on your question

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am having the same problem as you described

Comment: I am having the same problem. So I will try to answer to your questions:
2) I would not use word 'session'. Just check the checkbox "I'm not a robot" and wait some time (about 1 minute) and the warning "Verification expired" automatically appers in recaptcha box. After that it is not possible to check it again. 
3) http://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/
4) yes
5) latest.
;
Error "Cannot read property 'then' of null" appears in Chrome. Different error appears in Firefox: "TypeError: a.jc is null".

My guess is that this is Google issue and they will fix it soon.

Comment: Sorry, the page got deleted on an update, I have added it back. 

I added the following to the onLoadCallback method:
'expired-callback': captchaExpired

And then:

grecaptcha.reset();

This seems to have worked but not sure if this is the proper way to circumvent the issue?

Comment: there is a post on the recaptcha google group, the recaptcha team is monitoring that group and I hope we'll find the answer soon:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/ATcajrsErHM

Comment: The page referenced in your post, http://kexp-web1.cac.washington.edu/GCap.html , does not exist any more.  I would be interested in answering your question if you could post the code.